# Replace string based on an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of values

```
array(
    'FDR' => 'Franklin D Roosevelt',
    'JFK' => 'John F Kennedy'
)
```

and I have a variable

```
$variable = 'FDR'
```

I want to change the variable to say Franklin D Roosevelt based on the fact that the array points FDR to Franklin D Roosevelt.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest solution based on your description:

```
$arr = array('FDR' => 'Franklin D Roosevelt', 'JFK' => 'John F Kennedy');

$var = 'FDR';

$var = (array_key_exists($var, $arr) ? $arr[$var] : $var);

echo $var; // Franklin D Roosevelt
```

Or another way:

```
$arr = array('FDR' => 'Franklin D Roosevelt', 'JFK' => 'John F Kennedy');

$var = 'FDR';

foreach($arr as $i=>$a) {
    if ($i == $var) {
        $var = $a;
        break;
    }
}

echo $var; // Franklin D Roosevelt
```